# TestNG test skipped while running with groups and dataProvider values

Tags: maven, testng

Tests are skipped with below code,

```
@Test(groups = { "sanity", "prod" }, dataProviderClass = ReqRespDataProvider.class, dataProvider = "sampleTestData")
public void sampleMethodTest(Map<DataType, String> map){

}
```

Running with

```
mvn clean install test -Dgroups=sanity
```

Results:

```
Running TestSuite
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 5.426 sec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-Dgroups=sanity` on a Maven command line does nothing but defining a property meant to be used in the project's POM.

To define groups to test you have to [declare them for the Surefire Plugin accordingly](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html#Using_Groups):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
      <groups>${groups}</groups>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

BTW, `... install test ...` isn't necessary, since [invoking Maven's `install` phase passes the `test` phase anyway](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Usual_Command_Line_Calls).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already updated POM.xml file in my project. But still tests are getting skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
@BeforeSuite method was getting skipped while running test with groups tag. I have changed @BeforeSuite(alwaysRun = true) and all the groups tagged tests are picked up in run.